# Primefaces extensions DocumentViewer in hyphenated languages not working

Tags: primefaces, pdf.js, primefaces-extensions

I use pe:documentViewer for display documents and set 'locale' like `pt` (`pt_pt`,  `pt_br`, `pt-pt` or `pt-br`) but nothing happens and the actions continues in english. why?

My code is:

```
<pe:documentViewer locale="pt" height="#{previewHeight}" value="#{previewComponent.file}"/>
```

Comment: how about pt-PT or pt-BR?

Comment: basically when "locale" is hyphenated languages (like "pt-PT") the extension for documentViewer not working and the viewer keeps in English. why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solve by changing the locale javascript as it is a bug Primefaces Extension will not find the pt-BR,pt-PT:

```
&lt;pe:documentViewer value="#{document}" locale="pt" height="800"/&gt;

&lt;script type="text/javascript"&gt;

var src = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0].src.replace('#locale=pt','#locale=pt-BR');

document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0].setAttribute('src', src);

&lt;/script&gt;
```